# How to get rid of weird disk partitions on a Windows 10 on C drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

I am having an issue were I am unable to delete the weird partitions in C drive. When I right click, I get only the Help option available. For the first partition, other options are greyed out while help is only in black, while for the second partition, only the “Help” option is visible.

How would I fix this problem?

[image: Screenshot1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an EFI system partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/1087091/what-is-an-efi-system-partition)

Answer (score 0):

You ***really*** don't want to delete those.

- The EFI system partition is *required* for your computer to boot and is impossible to delete.
- The recovery partition exists to reinstall your operating system if something gets broken.

Note that the graphical view is misleading as to the size these take. It's split into almost thirds, where both the EFI and recovery partition are only responsible for about 0.2% of the space usage on your drive.